# Is there a way that we can let other buttons be freeze once a radio button has been selected i.e. now a different button cannot be selected?

Tags: java, android

Is there a way that we can let other buttons be freeze once a radio button has been selected i.e. now a different button cannot be selected? 
For instance, I am trying to create an app where a quiz is being taken and want that once one of the options is selected it cannot be changed for the particular question. How do I implement such a code?

Comment: typically you can use setEnabled(false)

Comment: setEnable (false) or setClickable (false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the callback for the button that was selected, use `setEnabled(false)` on all the others.

Alternatively, you could also disable all the buttons in the entire `RadioGroup` using something similar to the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
    radioGroup.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
}
```